# Observing LiveData from ViewModel

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a separate class in which I handle data fetching (specifically Firebase) and I usually return LiveData objects from it and update them asynchronously. Now I want to have the returned data stored in a ViewModel, but the problem is that in order to get said value, I need to observe the LiveData object returned from my data fetching class. The observe method required a LifecycleOwner object as the first parameter, but I obviously don't have that inside of my ViewModel and I know I am not supposed to keep a reference to the Activity/Fragment inside of the ViewModel. What should I do?

Comment: Related to https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/301

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) by Google developer Jose Alcérreca it is recommended to use a transformation in this case (see the "LiveData in repositories" paragraph) because **ViewModel** shouldn't hold any reference related to `View` (Activity, Context etc) because it made it hard to test.

Comment: have you managed to get Transformation working for you? My events aren't working

Comment: Transformations on their own do not work, since whatever code you write in the transformation is only attached to run when some entity observes _the transformation_.

Comment: I don't know why this is the recommended answer, it has nothing to do with the question. 2 years later, and we still don't know how to observe repository data changes in our viewmodel.

Comment: @Andrew Hi Andrew, I am curious. Why not observe data in the fragment as viewmodel.repository.liveModelData.observe {this, }

Comment: That doesn't answer the question? What if you need a specific value inside your viewmodel to do other operations and then serve it to the fragment??

Answer (score 42):

## Use Flow

#### The guideline in docs is misunderstood

> However ViewModel objects must never observe changes to lifecycle-aware observables, such as LiveData objects.

In this [Github issue](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/301#issuecomment-373834976), he describes that the situations that be applied the above rule are that observed lifecycle-aware observables are hosted by another lifecycle scope.
There is no problem that observes `LiveData` in `ViewModel` contains observed `LiveData`.

### Use Flow

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val myLiveData = MutableLiveData(1)

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            myLiveData.asFlow().collect {
                // Do Something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Use StateFlow

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val myFlow = MutableStateFlow(1)
    private val myLiveData = myFlow.asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
}
```

Requires `"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"` dependency

#### PS

The `asFlow` makes a flow that makes `LiveData` activate at starting `collect`. I think the solution with `MediatorLiveData` or `Transformations` and attaching a dummy observer doesn't have differences using the `Flow` except for emitting value from `LiveData` is always observed in the `ViewModel` instance.

Comment: This is good but where `asFlow` comes from? There is no name of dependency

Comment: @user924 you need to add in gradle `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0"` and then import `import androidx.lifecycle.asFlow`

Answer (score 36):

In [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) documentation

> However ViewModel objects must never observe changes to lifecycle-aware observables, such as LiveData objects.

Another way is for the data to implement RxJava rather than LiveData, then it won't have the benefit of being lifecycle-aware.

In google sample of [todo-mvvm-live-kotlin](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvvm-live-kotlin/), it uses a callback without LiveData in ViewModel.

I am guessing if you want to comply with the whole idea of being lifecycle-ware, we need to move observation code in Activity/Fragment. Else, we can use callback or RxJava in ViewModel.

Another compromise is implement MediatorLiveData (or Transformations) and observe (put your logic here) in ViewModel. Notice MediatorLiveData observer won't trigger (same as Transformations) unless it's observed in Activity/Fragment. What we do is we put a blank observe in Activity/Fragment, where the real work is actually done in ViewModel.

```
// ViewModel
fun start(id : Long) : LiveData<User>? {
    val liveData = MediatorLiveData<User>()
    liveData.addSource(dataSource.getById(id), Observer {
        if (it != null) {
            // put your logic here
        }
    })
}

// Activity/Fragment
viewModel.start(id)?.observe(this, Observer {
    // blank observe here
})
```

PS: I read [ViewModels and LiveData: Patterns + AntiPatterns](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) which suggested that Transformations. I don't think it work unless the LiveData is observed (which probably require it to be done at Activity/Fragment).

Comment: Did anything change in this regard? Or RX, callback or blank observe are only solutions?

Comment: Any solution to get rid of these blank observes?

Comment: Maybe using Flow (`mLiveData.asFlow()`) or `observeForever`.

Comment: Flow solution seems to work if you don't want to have/you don't need any observer logic in Fragment

Answer (score 29):

I think you can use observeForever which does not require the lifecycle owner interface and you can observe results from the viewmodel

Comment: this seems the right answer to me especially that in the docs about ViewModel.onCleared() is said:
"It is useful when ViewModel observes some data and you need to clear this subscription to prevent a leak of this ViewModel."

Comment: Sorry but `Cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread`

Comment: That seems quite legitimate. Though one has to save observers in the viewModel fields and unsubscribe at `onCleared`. As to the background thread - observe from main thread, that's it.

Comment: @Boken You can force `observeForever` to be invoked from main via `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { myvm.observeForever() }`

Comment: After few hours of research. I suppose the only good way to do this is using a blank observe in the view component because observeForever may cause problems when the view (that the observable supposed to be attached) is destroyed. This is what I could find, I am still on the question. I will update if I find a more convenient answer .

Answer (score 10):

[**Use Kotlin coroutines with Architecture components.**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)

You can use the `liveData` builder function to call a `suspend` function, serving the result as a `LiveData` object.

```
val user: LiveData<User> = liveData {
    val data = database.loadUser() // loadUser is a suspend function.
    emit(data)
}
```

You can also emit multiple values from the block. Each `emit()` call suspends the execution of the block until the `LiveData` value is set on the main thread.

```
val user: LiveData<Result> = liveData {
    emit(Result.loading())
    try {
        emit(Result.success(fetchUser()))
    } catch(ioException: Exception) {
        emit(Result.error(ioException))
    }
}
```

In your gradle config, use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0` or higher.

There is also an [article](https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-livedata-in-your-repository-there-are-better-options-25a7557b0730) about it.

**Update**: Also it's possible to change `LiveData<YourData>` in the `Dao` `interface`. You need to add the `suspend` keyword to the function:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM the_table")
suspend fun getAll(): List<YourData>
```

and in the `ViewModel` you need to get it asynchronously like that:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    allData = dao.getAll()
    // It's also possible to sync other data here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its been a while since the original post but I recently stumbled upon the same issue (also with Firebase) and I was able to solve it with Transformations.

I have a repository class that holds liveData objects, collected with Firebase's ValueEventListener.
The ViewModel hold a reference to this repository.

Now, in the ViewModel, instead of having a function that returns the LiveData value from the repository, and then pass it to the Fragment via an observer , like this:

```
fun getMyPayments(): LiveData<HashMap<String, Int>> {
    return repository.provideMyPayments()
}
```

I use a val with Transformations.map that represent the final result of the LiveData, after being processed by another function in the ViewModel:

```
val myRoomPaymentsList : LiveData<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Payment>>> = Transformations.map(repository.provideMyPayments()) {data ->
        getRoomPaymentsList(data)
    }
```

note that the first parameter is the data source which you observe and the second parameter is the result you want to get.
This val is a LiveData val that holds to the most current value from the repository and serves it as needed in the Fragment, keeping all the processing in the ViewModel and only the UI function inside the Framgent itself.

Then, inside my Fragment, I put an observer on this val:

```
viewModel.myRoomPaymentsList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    roomPayments = it
    graphFilterPeriod()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As an example, if you need to fetch an ID (as LiveData) and use it to make another call for LiveData. Store the ID in selectedID and the Transformations would observe that field and call getAllByID(selectedID) (also LiveData) whenever it changes.

```
var selectedID = MutableLiveData<Int>()

val objects = Transformations.switchMap(selectedID) { getAllByID(it) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there have already been amazing answers for this topic, but I wanted to add my own as well:

If you want to stick to `LiveData` you can always use `Transformations.map` so that you don't have to `observe` in the `ViewModel` but rather only in the `Fragment`/`Activity`.

Otherwise, you can use `SharedFlow`, a single event observable. For more, I have written an article here: https://coroutinedispatcher.com/posts/decorate_stateful_mvvm/

You don't have to pass  `viewLifecycleOwner` in the `ViewModel` because there is no point in calling `observe` in the `ViewModel` when the `View` just needs the latest result after all.

Answer (score 0):

I do it as followed without external libraries:

- In your ViewModel add a nullable property of type `Job`
- Add your code that you want to execute also in a property, like this:

Code:

```
private val watcherNotifications = Observer<MyType> {
    // Logic...
}
```

- Invoke the method `observeForever` on your `LiveData` and assign the resulting `Job` to your just-added property. The value is `watcherNotifications` or whatever you may have called it.
- Override method `onClear` on your `ViewModel` and call on your job property method `removeObserver(watcherNotifications)`

Answer (score 0):

**Most of the answers here are kind of wrong**.

**There is a reason why we are supposed to pass lifecycleOwner to the observer. We should never observe anything from `ViewModels`**

Never ever pass your activity, context or lifecycleOwner to the viewModel.
It all togather breaks the MVVM principle.

Here is how you get things done.

Suppose, there is a liveData coming from FireBase -> `LiveData<FirsbaseResult>`

You will just create a local liveData variable inside your viewModel like following:

`lateinit var localLiveData: LiveData<FirebaseResult>`

Then, just assign the coming liveData to your localLiveData.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
        lateinit var localLiveData: LiveData<FirebaseResult>
        
        fun getFireBaseData() {
            val firebaseLiveData = getResultFromFireBase() // Call function to get firebaseResult live Data
            localLiveData = firebaseLiveData
        }
    }
```

and now, you can easily observe this liveData inside your activity/fragment using Activity's scope.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val myViewModel= ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        myViewModel.getFireBaseData()
        myViewModel.localLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            // Happy Coding Here...
        }
    }
```