# How to pass data from repository to ViewModel using coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-architecture-components

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515997/observing-livedata-from-viewmodel) question gave me a general idea but I'm still struggling.

My fragment -

```
// Reset email sent observer
viewModel.isEmailSent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { flag ->
    onResetMailSent(flag)
})
```

My ViewModel -

```
val isMailSent: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(false)

isEmailSent = liveData {
                emit(firebaseAuthRepo.sendPasswordResetMail(emailId))
            }
```

My Repository -

```
suspend fun sendPasswordResetMail(emailId: String): Boolean {
   firebaseAuth?.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailId)
               ?.addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) { }
               }
               ?.addOnFailureListener {

               }
}
```

question -

1. How do I inform the viewmodel that the repo's 'addOnCompleteListener' or 'addOnFailureListener' has been called? I was thinking of returning a boolean flag but seems like I can't place a 'return' statement inside the listeners.
2. IDE says that the 'suspend' modifier is redundant. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html#suspendcoroutine) in this case it will basically work as a hook and you can handle the callback stuff with the `Continuation` object. We need this because `firebaseAuth` already runs on a separate thread. Try the method below

```
suspend fun sendPasswordResetMail(emailId: String): Boolean {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        suspendCoroutine { cont ->
            firebaseAuth?.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailId)
                ?.addOnCompleteListener {
                        cont.resume(it.isSuccessful)
                }
                ?.addOnFailureListener {
                    cont.resumeWithException(it)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I return the boolean flag?

Comment: `cont.resume(it.isSuccessful)` is the boolean which you will get as return value . Or an exception if fails .

Comment: Ah, okay. I tried this but now neither of the listeners are called. Debugger says no executable code found at line where 'cont.resume(it.isSuccessful)' or 'cont.resumeWithException(it)' is.

Comment: This worked in one instant. We are Resigning the job. :) Thanks.