# How to retrieve db data in View Model using LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack, android-livedata

After a successful sign-in with Firebase Auth, my Fragment receives the current user details. With these, I would like to look for an existing db record with the same user ID, and if not existing, persist it.

**My Fragment**

```
private fun onSignInResult(result: FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult) {
    if (result.resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.let {
            viewModel.setFirebaseUser(it)
        }
        findNavController().navigate(SignInFragmentDirections.navSignInToHome())
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class UserViewModel(
    private val usersRepository: UsersRepository
    ) : ViewModel() {

    private val currentUser: MutableLiveData<User> = MutableLiveData()

    fun setFirebaseUser(fireBaseUser: FirebaseUser) {
        with (fireBaseUser) {
            currentUser.value = User(uid, email, displayName)
            usersRepository.getUser(uid).let {
                if (it.value != null) {
                    Log.i("UserViewModel", "User Found")
                    currentUser.value = it.value
                } else {
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        Log.i("UserViewModel", "Coroutine scope")
                        val user = User(uid, email, displayName)
                        usersRepository.insertUser(user)
                        currentUser.value = user
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UsersRepository**

```
interface UsersRepository {
    fun getUser(id: String): LiveData<User?>
}
```

This code actually works, but after a second or successive sign-in, the existing user is never found and the `usersRepository#insertUser()` function is always executed, that being caused by `usersRepository#getUser()` always returning a null user.
I think this is due to the fact that I am not observing correctly the LiveData object, but I am not sure how am I supposed to observe it in the View Model.

Before answering, please note that I would like to learn the best practices possibly using only kotlin - jetpack libraries Room, LiveData, ViewModel (no RxJava nor other DI modules).

Should I move the logic into the Fragment so that I can observe the LiveData object? Or should the repository return a User instead of a LiveData?

---

**EDIT:**
Adding an Observer with `repoUser.observeForever()` (and removing it after the first invocation) works. Not sure indeed whether this is the best way.

Ref:
[Observing LiveData from ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515997/observing-livedata-from-viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

### First of all

I assume that you have another class called for example UserRepositoryImpl which in it you implement the functions that are in the interface but you forgot to include it.

**If you don't have one then where do you implement the functions**

Here is an example of implementing the getUser fun

```kotlin
fun getUser(id:String):LiveData<User> {
    val userData = MutableLiveData<User>()
    Firestore.collection(Constants.USER_COLLECTION)
    .whereEqualTo("id",id)
    .addSnapshotListener{value,error ->
    
        if(error != null){
          Log.e(TAG,error.getMessage())  
          return@SnapshotListener
        }
        
        for(documentSnapshot in value.documents){
            val user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User::class.java)
            
            userData.value = user
        }
        
    }
    
    return userData
}
```

Then you can get it in the viewmodel as you already did

```kotlin
usersRepository.getUser(uid).let {
                if (it.value != null) {
                    Log.i("UserViewModel", "User Found")
                    currentUser.value = it.value
                } else {
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        Log.i("UserViewModel", "Coroutine scope")
                        val user = User(uid, email, displayName)
                        usersRepository.insertUser(user)
                        currentUser.value = user
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

**Important** check your rules in firesotre for the read and write permissions, if they are set to false then set them to true and this will probably be your problem.

---

### Best Practices

- Use dagger hilt Dagger hilt is a dependency injection library you can learn more about it [here](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOVP.z4LhGouTx00H1r9uxlY8cAHgFo%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=477a9db6952744dbb6b35d4d5b97987b506d0077d3f9607e7008ca8da851b715&ipo=videos)
  and trust me it will make things a lot easier
- Don't expose a mutable live data to the ui

In your code you exposed a mutable live data to the ui to observe and this isn't good because the Ui shouldn't edit the data in anyway its only propose is to display the data and send the ui events to the view model

So a better way to add a live data to your viewmodel will be like this

```kotlin
   // This is the one that will be edited in the view model
 private val _currentUser: MutableLiveData<User> = MutableLiveData()
// This is the one that the ui will observe
  val currentUser get() = _currentUser
```

I know that these aren't all the best practices you could implement but these are the ones that I have seen

---

I hope this help,let me know if you encountered any problems

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but I have to make some annotations: 1) Yes for sure I have implemented the repository interface, otherwise how should I run it and expose here the resulting behavior as I did? I decided to not add it to the question by purpose, since it's irrelevant. 2) you are pasting the solution I already gave in my question, without answering 3) I am not exposing the MutableLiveData in the UI, how can you say that? 4) the tools you suggest are exactly the ones I wrote I would like to avoid

Comment: @perissf Adding the repository implementation to the question is highly recommended because the issue might be from the implementation -- and yes it might be this easy --, For the DI you asked for the best practices and this is the best practices despite you saying no DI. and please add the full code to better understand your problem and provide an answer. At the end we are here to learn and discuss ;) --- If you can, show me the implementation of the getUser fun ---